# How to check whether the page content is been managed by blocks, views or anything?

Tags: 7

I have one webpage (created in Drupal 7) and I am not able to figure out wether the content comes from blocks, views or anything else? I have checked blocks and views but there it is not appearing. How to check?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please improve your question thoroughly. Please use semantic tags that fit your problem and your Drupal version. Please fix spelling. Please provide more information. As it is now your question very likely will get closed as too broad or too low quality.

Comment: You can always check the HTML code with your browser's inspector and check the classes of surrounding divs. That is something you could post here as well.

Comment: where should we can search the classes got from inspector. means that are not available in theme .css file also

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in as administrator of the site, usually you should see either a edit button (for full nodes) or a contextual link for editing the a view or a node. You will need to have permission to see contextual links.